# Arrow key controlled Python menu

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a terminal based program that starts with a  main menu. I would like the user to be able to press the up and down keys to highlight each of the options. This can just be done by reprinting the menu. And once this is done the user should be able to press enter to select the option triggering another section of code. At the moment I'm having trouble getting the program to see when I'm pressing the up and down keys. Any help with this world be appreciated.
I am happy to include pygame in the program so long as I don't have to start up the graphical window.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What platform are you on? Perhaps you can use [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html)?

Comment: That which @univerio suggested if you're environment is UNIX-like. Suggestion: design the select mechanism with characters

ex/ 'h' for help, 'm' for main menu, 'q' to quit etc.

Comment: although to be honest its much easier to use a real GUI framework like wx than curses for this ... console gui's are actually more complex often times ...

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I found this website that gave the code for a menu: http://www.promisc.org/blog/?p=33    I just edited the cmenu list to put in what was displayed and the command which i defined above